# biblatex authoryear change dots to commas

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

With the *authoryear* citation style, in the bibliography theres a dot displayed after every the title. Like in this example:

[image]

My requirement is to change this dot, to a comma in every document type.

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}` If that does not help we need to see a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Your image already shows modifications or a non-standard style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

Turns the main unit punctuation from a period (full stop) followed by a space into a comma followed by a space.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}
\cite{malinowski,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]